Unable to install azureml-dataset-runtime
I am using a M1 mac running on MacOS Sonoma 14.7. I have project dependencies that I need to install to execute the project. I am using Python version 3.8. When I install the same dependencies on Windows machine it works fine.
Below are the dependencies.
azureml
azureml-core
azureml-dataset-runtime
azureml-interpret
azureml-monitoring
azureml-responsibleai
azureml-telemetry
azure-identity 
azure-mgmt-resource
azureml-dataset-runtime
numpy
pandas>=1.5.0
pandera
torch 
neuralforecast 
datasetsforecast 
hyperopt
matplotlib
darts
mlflow

when I try to install I get the following error
Collecting pyarrow<4.0.0,>=0.17.0 (from azureml-dataset-runtime)
  Using cached pyarrow-3.0.0.tar.gz (682 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [77 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.9"' don't match your environment
      Collecting cython>=0.29
        Using cached Cython-3.0.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
      Collecting numpy==1.16.6
        Using cached numpy-1.16.6.zip (5.1 MB)
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
        Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-75.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
      Collecting setuptools_scm
        Using cached setuptools_scm-8.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.6 kB)
      Collecting wheel
        Using cached wheel-0.44.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.3 kB)
      Collecting packaging>=20 (from setuptools_scm)
        Using cached packaging-24.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
      Collecting typing-extensions (from setuptools_scm)
        Using cached typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
      Collecting tomli>=1 (from setuptools_scm)
        Using cached tomli-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10.0 kB)
      Using cached Cython-3.0.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
      Using cached setuptools-75.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
      Using cached setuptools_scm-8.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (43 kB)
      Using cached wheel-0.44.0-py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
      Using cached packaging-24.1-py3-none-any.whl (53 kB)
      Using cached tomli-2.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
      Using cached typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
      Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
        Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): started
        Building wheel for numpy (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [17 lines of output]
            Running from numpy source directory.
            /private/var/folders/dq/t1v4d77x37gdhkz5rcd1wq680000gp/T/pip-install-822946xd/numpy_36feab41475244f49084f939ee233e61/numpy/distutils/misc_util.py:476: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
              return is_string(s) and ('*' in s or '?' is s)
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
              File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
              File "/private/var/folders/dq/t1v4d77x37gdhkz5rcd1wq680000gp/T/pip-install-822946xd/numpy_36feab41475244f49084f939ee233e61/setup.py", line 419, in <module>
                setup_package()
              File "/private/var/folders/dq/t1v4d77x37gdhkz5rcd1wq680000gp/T/pip-install-822946xd/numpy_36feab41475244f49084f939ee233e61/setup.py", line 398, in setup_package
                from numpy.distutils.core import setup
              File "/private/var/folders/dq/t1v4d77x37gdhkz5rcd1wq680000gp/T/pip-install-822946xd/numpy_36feab41475244f49084f939ee233e61/numpy/distutils/core.py", line 26, in <module>
                from numpy.distutils.command import config, config_compiler, \
              File "/private/var/folders/dq/t1v4d77x37gdhkz5rcd1wq680000gp/T/pip-install-822946xd/numpy_36feab41475244f49084f939ee233e61/numpy/distutils/command/config.py", line 19, in <module>
                from numpy.distutils.mingw32ccompiler import generate_manifest
              File "/private/var/folders/dq/t1v4d77x37gdhkz5rcd1wq680000gp/T/pip-install-822946xd/numpy_36feab41475244f49084f939ee233e61/numpy/distutils/mingw32ccompiler.py", line 34, in <module>
                from distutils.msvccompiler import get_build_version as get_build_msvc_version
            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.msvccompiler'
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
        Running setup.py clean for numpy
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
      
        × python setup.py clean did not run successfully.
        │ exit code: 1
        ╰─> [10 lines of output]
            Running from numpy source directory.
      
            `setup.py clean` is not supported, use one of the following instead:
      
              - `git clean -xdf` (cleans all files)
              - `git clean -Xdf` (cleans all versioned files, doesn't touch
                                  files that aren't checked into the git repo)
      
            Add `--force` to your command to use it anyway if you must (unsupported).
      
            [end of output]
      
        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
        ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
      Failed to build numpy
      ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (numpy)
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

This error occurs when an attempt is made to install pyarrow. How can I fix this issue?

For some reason pyarrow is pinned <4.0.0,>=0.17.0. So this is trying to install 3.0.0, which is from 2021 at which time there were no M1 wheels. I suggest you figure out with pipdeptree why pyarrow is using such an old version (and potentially update because python 3.8 is getting less supported).

The problem is that azureml-dataprep-native is not built for any Python version on M1. Secondly, there is no source distribution. Any help to fix this would be really helpful.

you need to use azureml-dataprep instead if you want the source.
